# DevTest Labs - Custom image with 2 NICs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-devtest-labs

I know DevTest Labs is still in Preview, but I'm currently trying to develop using the latest functionalities from Azure (not classic).

I have my own linux VHD and I decided to created a custom image under DevTest Labs. For my VM to work properly I need to add a secondary NIC to it, but I couldn't see any option/functionality to do so. I'm assuming there's another hidden way to create a secondary NIC(with Powershell, xplat-cli, wizardry..)or worst case scenario, there's no way to create a secondary NIC.

Any input if that's even possible yet ?

Answer (score 0):

The primary building block of Azure Resource Management model is the Resource Manager Template, if you create a template that specifies the solution you want to create you can import that template into DevTest labs. Then deploy that as needed.

You could use [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-1-vm-loadbalancer-2-nics) template as a starting point there are plenty of others at the [Azure Quickstart Templates Site](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/)

They take a little hacking and getting used to, but once you figure them out they are a good way of managing resources.

There is also a an [ARM template visualiser](http://armviz.io/#/) which is starting to get quite useful.

Comment: Thanks for the nice references!
So I could only add a second NIC if creating a ARM template ? Can't I just attach a new NIC interface to the VM ? There's an interface in the portal to do so, but the new NIC is not visible as an option.

Comment: It appears that it can't be done with the portal. When you go to attach a NIC, the attach button is greyed out if it already has one. This link shows exactly how to do this with powershell or arm template: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-network-deploy-multinic-arm-template/

Comment: I managed to create my template.json but I'm getting the following error when I try to run it:
"New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment : 10:15:58 - Resource Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/virtualMachines 'testlab/testvm2' fa
iled with message 'No registered resource provider found for location 'westeurope' and API version '2015-05-01-preview'
 for type 'labs/virtualMachines'. The supported api-versions are '2015-05-21-preview'. The supported locations are 'eas
tus, westus, westeurope, eastasia, eastus2, japaneast, japanwest, centralus'.'

I also tried version 2015-05-21-preview which also failed.